# Angular 2 testing karma with webpack Can't find variable: Map

Tags: javascript, testing, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my directive with karma and webpack.
This is the karma config file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ["jasmine"],
        files: [
            {
            pattern: 'directive.spec.ts',
            watched: false
        }],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {
            'directive.spec.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: [
            "PhantomJS"
        ],
        singleRun: true,
        reporters: ['mocha'],
        webpack: {
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
                modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '.'],
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [{
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                }]
            },
            stats: {
                colors: true,
                reasons: true
            },
            debug: true,
            devtool: 'inline-source-map'
        }
    });
};
```

**And the directive.spec.ts:**

```
import { MyDirective } from './directive';
import {TestComponent} from './test';
import {
  async,
  inject,
  TestBed,
} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('TestComponent', () => {

  let fixture: any;

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ TestComponent, MyDirective]
  })
  .createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

  it('should work', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
```

But when I am trying to run my test I am getting this error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR   ReferenceError: Can't find
>   variable: Map   at directive.spec.ts:1380

What am I missing here?

Comment: The line number is huge, so I presume it's treating your imports as if they were in the file. I suspect that `MyDirective` or `TestComponent` uses a `Map` variable, somewhere, but doesn't define it or `import` it from somewhere. You could see if/where `Map` is referenced in those files, and figure out where it's not been imported from or defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps. It worked for me:
1) Create a "karma-main.js" file with following code

```js
require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

var appContext = require.context('<Source code root folder>', true, /\.spec\.ts/); // Assuming test case files ends with spec.ts

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

2) Your karma.conf.js file should look like

```js
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config')

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-PhantomJS-launcher',
      'karma-webpack'
    ],

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: '<relative path to karma-main.js>', watched: false }
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '<relative path to karma-main.js>': ['webpack']
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my guess: somewhere in the code you use a class `Map` which appeared in ES6. But PhantomJS doesn't know about this class yet since it's something too new.

So there are 3 choices:

- Get rid of usage of `Map` and use only current JS features (like Object properties) - the cleanest approach.
- Use transpiler for transforming your ES6 code into ES5 that's well understood by modern browser. This has huge disadvantages as it will mess with your line numbers and you may have to sacrifice the possibility to debug some of the code.
- Use polyfills that implement ES6 features as functions in external libraries (as Sachin Gaur [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355144/886697))